# Summary is not appeared in the documentation using Sandcastle Help File Builder (SHFB)

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, sandcastle

I have used Sandcastle for documentation of my C# desktop windows application. I am using Sandcastle Help File Builder (SHFB) and included *.sln or *.csproj file to extract the info and make it as a *chm documentation file. It compiled but didn't work properly as I have already added my comments like this

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Create form to display the GUI to process the data of CPRI and XIO links in side the data grids.
    /// </summary>
```

but it is not appear in the documentation(chm) file in FORM1 class and also in other classes. I have already included other summary in the similar manner in the other classes but it was also not include.Any idea?

I do n't know where I am lacking.....Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. By default in the "visibility" section in Sandcastle Help File Builder (SHFB), Document Private and Document Private fields are false and when I turn it True it worked for me.

[image: Set the Document Private and Document Private fields in the visibility section to True]